# I'm trying to get a specific out put based on what is in the textbox

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a specific out put based on what is in the text box, with java script but all the code I'm using only works for numbers not with "text". When I replace the numbers with "text" it outputs no matter whats in the text box.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <body>
     <imput id="x"value=""/>
     <button on Click="myFunction():">Try it</button>
     <p id="demo"></p>
     <script>
       function myFunction() {
         var qpw = "eighteen";
         var w = (qpw = "eighteen") ? "dieciocho":"no caps";
         document.getElementByld("demo").innerHTML = w + "";
       }
     </script>
     <script>
       function myFunction() {
         var qpe = "blue";
         var e = (qpe = "blue") ? "azul":"no caps";
         document.getElementByld("demo").innerHTML = e + "";
       }
     </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: give your functions different names

Comment: Use `==` or `===` instead of `=` in your ternary, example `(qpw == "eighteen") ?`...

Comment: Can you review the javascript code you posted ? It contains the same function ( myFunction defined twice ) + a DOM tag called imput ( most likely you meant input ) any other things you want to review ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use the wrong equals sign for boolean logic:

```
var w = (qpw = "eighteen") ? "dieciocho":"no caps";
```

should be:

```
var w = (qpw == "eighteen") ? "dieciocho":"no caps";
```

or more, appropriately:

```
var w = (qpw === "eighteen") ? "dieciocho":"no caps";
```

Here is a full explanation on the usage of the equals: [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

There are a number of typos in your code that, I assume, are just simple mistakes, I put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/3qqxcboq/1/) of your issue and solution.

I removed the inline javascript declaration from your html and added an id to the button:

```
<input id="x"value=""/>
 <button id="btn">Try it</button>
 <p id="demo"></p>
```

I then set the click event handler in javascript to the button:

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = myFunction;
```

I then removed the double functions and created one single function that checks against the user input:

```
function myFunction() {
    var userData = document.getElementById('x').value;
   var qpe = "blue";
    var qpw = "eighteen";
    var e = (userData == qpe) ? "azul": (userData == qpw)? "dieciocho" :"no caps";
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e + "";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiply errors in your code:

First of all:

```
<button on Click="myFunction():">Try it</button>
```

Should have been: (See the attribute name and the colon->semicolon)

```
<button onclick="myFunction();">Try it</button>
```

Secondly you cannot define two functions with the same name, the last will simply just override the first defined one... Which means all of this code is not used:

```
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
   var qpw = "eighteen";
   var w = (qpw = "eighteen") ? "dieciocho":"no caps";
   document.getElementByld("demo").innerHTML = w + "";
 }
 </script>
```

Thirdly you one line if statement is wrong:

```
var e = (qpe = "blue") ? "azul":"no caps";
```

Should have been: (two equal signs are used for loose comparison (Three equal signs are used for strict comparison. For instance `"1" == 1` but `"1" !== 1`))

```
var e = (qpe == "blue") ? "azul":"no caps";
```

Also there is not html element called `<imput>` I think you meant `<input>`:

```
<input id="x"value=""/>
```